# Exception in Merging 2 List

Tags: java, exception

I have merged 2 List and able to get data.

But when there is any exception in List1 then other List2 also does not get displayed.

```
List newList = new ArrayList();
newList.addAll(listOne);
newList.addAll(listTwo);
```

So I need to display at least 1 list even if the other list has an Exception.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Although you should probably check why adding the elements fails and resolve that, a way to solve your problem is the following:

```
public void addAllIgnoreException(List baseList, List listToBeAdded){
  try {
    baseList.addAll(listToBeAdded);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //log the exception
  }  
}
```

You can use this method to add the elements of 'listToBeAdded' to 'baseList' without having any exceptions:

```
List newList = new ArrayList();
addAllIgnoreException(newList, listOne);
addAllIgnoreException(newList, listTwo);
```

Comment: I don't think this should even be suggested. Adding two lists is an operation which should not be throwing an exception unless something is going very wrong. Wrapping a try/catch simply hides a severe underlying problem.

Comment: It is clear the guy who asked this question does not care about the severe underlying problem, otherwise he would have stated what this problem was... So I am giving him a solution based on the information he is giving.

Comment: @Fortega: my experience of answering questions here has learnt me that newbies, most of the time, don't read the error message they get and don't even think it might be useful. I've asked them to post the stack trace so many times that I start being desperate. They also don't know that Google might help and the documentation exists, most of the time.